# How to convert Task Http.RawError Http.Response to Task String (Int, Int)

Tags: elm

There are a type and a task

```
type Msg
  = Fail String
  | Success (Int, Int)


makeRequest =
  let
    req =
      { verb = "GET"
      , headers = []
      , url = "http://localhost:8080"
      , body = empty
      }
  in
    Task.perform Fail Success <| send defaultSettings req
```

The argument of `Fail` constructor is for error message (just `"Error"`), first argument of `Succeess` is for `status` from `Http.Response`, second is for size of `value` from `Http.Response`.

How to convert `Task Http.RawError Http.Response` to `Task String (Int, Int)`?

I'm looking at `Task.map` and `Tsk.mapError` and I don't understand how to combine them. Am I on a right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Task.map` and `Task.mapError` to achieve your results.

First off, you'll need a way to determine the size of your Http Response. Since it can be either a string or binary blob, and blob is [not yet supported](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#Value), you could define a function like this:

```elm
httpValueSize : Http.Value -> Int
httpValueSize val =
  case val of
    Text str -> String.length str
    Blob blob -> Debug.crash "Blobs have no implementation yet"
```

Now you can use the mapping functions in your task like this:

```elm
send defaultSettings req
  |> Task.map (\r -> (r.status, httpValueSize r.value))
  |> Task.mapError (always "Error")
  |> Task.perform Fail Success
```

You could also do this without the mapping functions like so:

```elm
send defaultSettings req
  |> Task.perform (always <| Fail "Error") (\r -> Success (r.status, httpValueSize r.value))
```